# Invalid trace at line 1? how to fix the line checker in java

Tags: java, stack-trace

I created a stack tracer program and it is not reading the input and saying there is an "invalid trace at line 1" (the error is starting at the very beginning of the file).

Error shows as:

```
    Testing input/output... . . . . . . . error in 
    ../../../testCases/input.0.12:
    --- solution_output.0.txt    2019-01-29 20:39:55.588725770 -0500
    +++ student_output.0.txt    2019-01-29 20:39:55.580725101 -0500
    @@ -1,4 +1,3 @@
    -Invalid trace at line 1
     Not all functions returned
     Stack trace:
     Iq1lUVw0YqwPJJe8xXMxFY
```

I've tried changing the line counter (lineNumber function) but it makes sense that it is initialized at 0.
I think maybe the output was expecting a different line # than what I gave it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Driver_prj0 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;

Stack<String> callStack = new Stack<String>();

int lineNumber = 0;

int maximum_depth = 0;
while (input.hasNext()) {
  line = input.nextLine();
  lineNumber++;

  if (line.startsWith("call ")) {

    String fname = line.substring(5);

    callStack.push(fname);
  }

  else {

    String fname = line.substring(7);

    if (callStack.empty()) {
      System.out.println("Invalid trace at line " + lineNumber);
      System.out.println("Returning from " + fname + " which was not called");
      System.out.println("Stack trace:");
      while (!callStack.empty()) {
        System.out.println(callStack.pop());
      }
      return;
    }

    else {
      if (callStack.peek().equals(fname)) {
        callStack.pop();

      }

      else {
        System.out.println("Invalid trace at line " + lineNumber);
        System.out.println("Returning from " + fname + " instead of " + callStack.peek());
        System.out.println("Stack trace:");
        while (!callStack.empty()) {
        System.out.println(callStack.pop());
      }
      return;
      }
    }
  }

  if (maximum_depth < callStack.size()) {
    maximum_depth = callStack.size();
  }
}

if (callStack.empty()) {
  System.out.println("Valid trace");
  System.out.println("Maximum call depth was " + maximum_depth);
}

else {
  System.out.println("Not all functions returned");
  System.out.println("Stack trace:");
  while (!callStack.empty()) {
        System.out.println(callStack.pop());
      }
      return;
}
}
}
```

should return "Valid trace / Maximum call depth was ", or the correct error message that should not start on line 1.

Comment: What do your input files look like, and how are you getting the input into your app, are you pasting it into your app line by line?

Comment: I am inputting the files in the command line as `java Driver_prj0 < input_1.txt` not line by line. One of the input files looks like: `call read_input
call istream::operator<<
return istream::operator<<
call istream::operator<<
return istream::operator<<
return read_input
call solve
call log
return log
call abs
return abs
call ostream::operator>>
return ostream::operator>>
return solve`

Comment: Ok, got it. Have you tried stepping through your code line by line in a debugger to see if it's doing what you expect?

Comment: I haven't used a debugger, but I tried with 4 different input files and all works correctly. The error above was received when an unknown input file was put in my program. There is no way to see the contents of the test input file that is receiving the error.

Comment: I added print lines to confirm the correct output of each line and that seemed to be fine.

Comment: If 4 different input files worked correctly, but 1 doesn't, what's different about this one file?